# mongodb full text search advice multiple words

Tags: python, search, mongodb, full-text-search

I am trying to have some form of fulltext search for one of my mongodb collections (a la [flowdock](http://blog.nodeta.com/2011/03/30/full-text-search-with-mongodb-flowdock-style/)).
I create a _keywords entry for each document and populate it with lowercased words from the other fields in that document. I then search it like this (prefixed search) ex. searchString = 'car'

```
found_shots = connection.Shot.find({'_keywords': re.compile('^%s' % searchString.lower())}).limit(limit).skip(skip)
```

The problem is when I try to search on multiple words ( ex. searchstring= ['car','online']

```
regex1 = re.compile('^%s' % searchStrings[0].lower())
regex2 = re.compile('^%s' % searchStrings[1].lower())
found_shots = connection.Shot.find({'$and':[{'_keywords':regex1},{'_keywords':regex2}]}).limit(limit).skip(skip)
```

That does not work. any ideas please?

Comment: Which version of mongo are you running because $and is only 1.9.x and above

Comment: @Sammaye: 1.8.2 and you are right. I was under the impression I updated it to 2.0 for testing but I didn't. My bad. Would my code work for 2.0? Is that a good way of doing it? Bad? is there another way except running 2 different queries and ANDing them in python?

Comment: should do, the regex object might not but just replace that with the standard // string if not

Comment: Whether there is a better way or not depends on the exact type of search query you are doing. if you are purposefully using the $and to conjoin the two statements then yea that is best but otherwise a better method might be a $or.

Comment: im doing a realtime search from my extjs front end in a datagrid. Basically it works for the first word i enter in the search box (it finds all rows that have a word in the _keyword field that start with the search word) and after that i need an and (find all rows that have in the _keyword field words that start with word1 and word2)

Comment: Then the $and is the right way cos you are doing, as we would in google, "mongo"+"db" (if I read your last statement right, I'm a bit tired so I may not have).

Comment: though you could also do a $in with the regexs, but both are the same really. $in might.....*might*...be a bit faster on index.

Comment: that's what i was thinking also. Although the indexing part is *mostly* a non issue with the database for this project as it's not that big and it's gonna be hosted locally. Btw, if you could provide an answer would be great so I can accept it.

Comment: Posted one that answers this question. Glad to be of help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$and` is only available in 1.9.x.

Since you are using 1.8.2 it does not work correctly.

If you upgrade you will get the latest set of commands and you will be able to use the $and command.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB 2.6 can now allow full text searching using the `$text` command combined with a FTS index.